# Счетчик в ассемблере

Tags: ассемблер

Есть вот такой код:

```
    masm                                     
model small 
.stack 100h
.data            
a equ 3        
b equ 4       
c equ 6        
CT db ?      
.code           
   stt:mov ax,@data   
        mov ds,ax     
    mov al, a          
whil:mov CT, al          
         cmp al, b       
         jnc repa          
         inc al           
         and al,0fh    
         jmp whil        
repa:dec al            
         and al,0fh      
        mov CT, al      
        cmp al, c         
        jc repa           
        jz repa          
        mov ax,4c00h  
        int 21h               
       end stt
```

В это программе что написана выше необходимо произвести изменения

```
begin
CT:=a;
While Con_1 do Opr_1;
Repeat Opr_2 Until Con_2
End.
```

У меня.

```
Con_1 это СТ < b 
 Opr_1   это  CT:=CT+1
Con_2 CT>=c
Opr_2 CT:=CT-1
```

Comment: "*необходимо изменить операторы*" - что-что? Если нужно реализовать какой-то алгоритм, то и описывайте его, нормальными словами, а не через шифровку. И уберите из кода бессмысленные комментарии  типа "определение сегмента данных", "сравнение с параметром", etc .Из-за этого мусора код вообще не читается.

Comment: Есть программа в неё вместо операторов что написаны в **While** заменить их на  **Con_1 and Opr_1** для Repeat также, толтко операторы **номер 2**

Comment: А что такое Con_1, Opr_1, Con_2 и Opr_2 - мы должны сами придумать?

Comment: Con_1 это СТ < b 
     Opr_1   это  CT:=CT+1
    Con_2 CT>=c
    Opr_2 CT:=CT-1

Comment: Спасибо за пример..Проблема просто вот в чем, до вчерашнего дня я ассемблер в глаза не видел..только Java.. И тут мне дают  этот код, что бы я его изменил...в вопросе написаны операторы т.е. While(CT<b) {..СТ++},и такое же для repeat

Answer (score 3):

Я так и не понял ничего в вашей шифрограмме, но на всякий случай пример. 
Реализация циклов с пред- и постусловиями на ассемблере очень простая, применяйте творчески:

```
; ----------------------------------
section .text
global main
; ----------------------------------
main:
    xor edx, edx
    mov eax, 4
;   while( eax > 0 ) {
;       edx++;
;   }
;
;   оно же
;
;   While eax > 0 do edx++, eax--
loop1:
    or eax, eax
    jz next1
    inc edx
    dec eax
    jmp loop1

next1:
;   do
;   {
;        edx++;
;        eax++;
;   } while( eax < 10 );
;
;   оно же
;
;   Repeat eax++, edx++ Until eax < 10
loop2:
    inc eax
    inc edx
    cmp eax, 10
    jl loop2

    ret
; ----------------------------------
```

Comment: А пример отлично привели с коментариями высокого уровня

Comment: **Спасибо**  Попробую что то сообразить... А что такое в моем коде **jc**, **jz** и **repa**

Comment: `jl`, `jz` - условные переходы (переходы на указанную метку, выполняющиеся при выполнении определенных условий - в данном случае **L**ess и **Z**ero, т.е. результат сравнения - "меньше", и результат операции равен 0 соответственно). Условный переход `jc` тоже бывает, но вам это пока не нужно. `repa` - название метки, на которую осуществляется переход.

Comment: Можете это перевести на ассемблер(((    **While(CT<b) { CT++;}.  Repeat  CT--;  Until(CT>=c) ну и что бы СТ не быть больше 15 что то такое and all,0f h ......**

Comment: Вроде бы >= это **ge**..

Comment: Эти все значения из моей программы что в самом верху(в описании)

Comment: Sorry, но с такими вопросами вам сначала букварь по ассемблеру читать. Или - на биржу фрилансеров, искать исполнителя.

Comment: Ну да, тут 3 строчки поменять в моей программе и все..

Comment: Меняйте, думаю, никто не против :)

Comment: @ДмитрийБережной это не сайт переводов с языка на язык. Пожалуйста либо изучайте ассемблер самостоятельно и приходите с конкретными вопросами, либо обратитесь к фрилансеру.